# Which firewall Ports do we need to open to Host a web site on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, web-applications

I have a new window based VM, it has IIS installed on it, I have developed my first .Net application with Web App and Web API. I would like to host this website so that we can access this web site from other computers. To Accomplish this do I have to request to open any firewall ports?
I have searched online and couldn't find any relevant answers for this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: usual port for http is 80 and should be the default port for the website you defined in IIS. The fact that you ask if you need to "request" a firewall opening lead me to think you're in an organization where it might be blocked, in which case this is not the place to ask the question, a better one might be your security team, or the ones responsible for setting up the VM.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have reached out to Security team and waiting for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP listens on port 80 by default.
HTTPS listens on port 443 by default.

However, you can listen on any port you want to:

1. Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
2. Select the Web site that you wish to configure.
3. In the Action pane, click Bindings.
4. Click Add to add a new site binding, or click Edit to change an
   existing binding.
5. Click OK to apply the changes.

See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/149605/how-to-change-the-tcp-port-for-iis-services

Bear in mind, if you use a non-default port, you will need to specify it explicitly in your URLs because your web browser will try 80/443 by default. E.g. if you change to port 1234, your URL would become http://www.example.com:1234

Comment: Thanks for your response.Will try changing the default port and will let you know.